# how to deal with percona keyserver with ansible

Tags: ansible, apt, percona

I have been trying to create a percona role in ansible and failing at it. I won't really say failing but it doesn't work as planned. Below is a snippet of the role

---

```
- name: Setting up percona server apt-key
  apt_key: 
    id=1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
    keyserver=keys.gnupg.net
    state=present
```

Upon running this I ended up with the following error:

```
failed: [192.168.56.107] => {"cmd": "apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
stderr: gpg: requesting key CD2EFD2A from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

As you can see ansible executes the following command: `apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A`, meanwhile the command that actually works, tested and recommended from percona [repository page](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation/apt_repo.html) 
is `apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A`. There is a difference in the commands the former is just --recv and the latter is --recv-keys. I have no idea how to make ansible run this commands either can using the ansible command module itself.

There is also this url found on percona download page to the [repo key](http://www.percona.com/downloads/RPM-GPG-KEY-percona) which can be used in the apt_key module instead of keyserver.

What I am interested in knowing is whether it's possible to make ansible run the actual apt_key commands with --recv-keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command should work for you:

```
- apt_key: url=http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/RPM-GPG-KEY-percona
           state=present
```

Comment: Url is the option I tried first, but the command is what I ended up using as it's more natural to use

Comment: @blacksensei You did not mention that you used url parameter in your original question. Also, using "command" module is generally an anti-pattern when a native module is available. Finally, your command will always show "changed" status when you run it, where as `apt_key` module will show proper changed/ok results based if something was done.

Comment: sorry for the miscommunication . In my post I attempted saying it with these: "There is also this url found on percona download page to the repo key which can be used in the apt_key module instead of keyserver. " . Now command being an anti-pattern is really new to me.I would do more search and if so, accept your answer rather.

Answer (score 3):

The [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/packaging/os/apt_key.py) for the apt_key module shows it building a command line using --recv but no mention of --recv-keys, so it doesn't look like you can use this module the way you want.  I would suggest [filing a feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/new) with the Ansible team to ask that they support this flag.

In the meantime you should be able to call apt-key manually via the command module.  The command would be virtually identical to what the debug output showed:

```
 - name: call apt_key manually
   command: apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
```